# Trigger When A New Pod Is Created on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, containers

I have a question that i have encountered on my project. In my project, briefly when a user  clicks to a button, a pod is created, does some operations and finally it is deleted. **I should measure the pods  running time and should decrease the duration from the credit of the user.** I want to manage it externally. Is it possible to understand and manage when a new pod has been created and destroyed from outside of the pods?
Thanks

Comment: It is certainly possible. You can watch the Kubernetes events and act on them. Events are created when pods are created and later deleted. I don't have a link to a good example, so I'll leave the searching to you. Good luck!

Comment: it is good approach but when I try it, an interesting case occures. The events from creation to termination process are
1:Schedule
2:Pulled
3:Created
4:Started
Even the pod is destroyed, not an event is occured for that. When i use kubectl get pods, i can not see the pod. Btw, i kill the pod with go-client library of the kubernetes. 
Do you have any idea why the final event is started, not killing?

Comment: You are correct. Have you tried using watch (https://www.baeldung.com/java-kubernetes-watch)? It seems to include delete for pods, but I haven't tried it personally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function I written is like following:

```
func WatchPods() {
    clientset, err := utils.NewClient(true)//create k8s client
    if err != nil {
    //handle error
    }

    watchlist := cache.NewListWatchFromClient(
        clientset.CoreV1().RESTClient(),
        string(v1.ResourcePods),
        "default",
        fields.Everything(),
    )
    _, controller := cache.NewInformer(
        watchlist,
        &v1.Pod{},
        0,
        cache.ResourceEventHandlerFuncs{
            AddFunc: func(obj interface{}) {//Calls when a new pod is created
                pod := obj.(*v1.Pod)
                //do whatever you want
                }

            },
            DeleteFunc: func(obj interface{}) {//Calls when a new pod is deleted
                pod := obj.(*v1.Pod)
                //do whatever you want
            },
        },
    )
    stop := make(chan struct{})
    defer close(stop)
    controller.Run(stop)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are multiple approach to this problem and I can suggest one.

If you are working with single container then `postStart` and `preStop` hooks can be useful. Here is the official doc of [container hooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#container-hooks).